# RequireJs exports 3-rd party dependency to late

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-strap, shim

I would like to add some plugin to my project based on angular + requirejs.
In my config I do:

```
shim: {
    'angular': {exports: 'angular', deps: ['jquery']},
    'angular-strap': {deps: ['angular']},
}
```

But when I write in my module:

```
define([
       'angular',
       'angular-strap'
]
```

Then I get console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined" in line where angular-strap module is registering

```
angular.module('mgcrea.ngStrap', [
```

If I remove angular-strap from define application is loaded properly and in global context I can see 'angular' object.

Comment: Try to remove the exports option for angular library. Make it something like this `anguar: ['jquery'], angular-strap: ['angular']`

Comment: Just make a mistake reading your question, sorry about that. But I think I have found the solution, check the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have inject angular-strap wrongly. You are supposed to use this syntax instead

```
angular.module('your_app name', ['deps']);
```

in your case it will be like this

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```